# Mathematics Wallpapers

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, intuition

I know that this sounds very silly. But I don't know where else to ask.

Is there a good free site for mathematics wallpapers , pictures etc ?

Most of the time it is very difficult to find exact picture to represent what is the lesson about !

Comment: A long time ago, as you can see from the title, IBM made available to schools a very large poster called *Men of Modern Mathematics*.  It is available in electronic form [here.](http://www.eamesoffice.com/the-work/men-of-modern-mathematics/)

Comment: Yes, google image search will provide what you want.